# http response returning webpage

Tags: c#, .net, http-post

Excuse any ignorance on my part with this methodology as it is somewhat new to me. I've been reading up on it as much as I can, but haven't been able to solve this yet.

I'm trying to accomplish a SSO with a vendor through an http post. Simple enough. I've done this in the past, but it usually returns a url that I can then redirect the user to. Unfortunately, with this vendor they are returning the entire page, html and all. Is this typical? If so, is my only solution to post this to a new window?

For reference, here's my code so far:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
var responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Does everything look normal and ok so far?

Comment: FYI, this is on a C#.net website. Sorry, I should have clarified this initially.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Comment: No problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: Does the SSO vendor have a name?

Comment: To finalize, I ended up using a hidden form post to just redirect the user to the site logged in. Just not used to having to use a form post in this manner. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal for a POST request to return a new web page.  I would think the redirect would be the abnormal case.

You're pretty vague about your app, so I'm not sure how you'll want to get the returned html shown to the user.

You might want to check out the WebClient class which could simplify your code considerably.

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var resultBytes = client.UploadData(new Uri("http://example.com"), "POST", data);
    }
```

Comment: Well, ideally we want to display the page in an iframe (not my first choice, but what is requested) or a new window, but not entirely sure how to do that. As far as simplified code, I initially used HttpTools.PostForm(link, postString, "NONJAVA") which seemed to work fine, just unsure if that is an ok method too.